# VSS snapshot - looking for info about "Auto_Release"

Tags: snapshot, volume-shadow-service, shadow-copy

Thanks, I cannot find any info at all about the "Auto_Release" attribute when creating a snapshot.
i use vshadow.exe to create snapshots and the snapshots are always created
"Attributes: Auto_Release No_Writers Differential"

I would like to understand about Auto_Release?
What rules determine when the snapshot is auto released by the Windows OS?

I read the microsoft docs at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vss/ne-vss-vss_snapshot_context
and searched the internet, forums, etc...

Comment: One way VSS shadow copies get auto released is when shadow storage space is exceeded. The storage space for shadow copies can be configured with the `vssadmin Resize ShadowStorage` command.